# UFT identifying checkbox as an Image and not able to click or set "ON" or "OFF" on it

Tags: extjs, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I have a check box in my application and UFT is identifying it as an "Image Object" and I am not able to click or Set "ON" or "OFF" anything on it.

My application is developed in EXT JS 4.2, Only for this checkbox I am facing this issue....for all others I got the webCheckButton. 
What can be done please help.

Comment: Can you check the source code and post it.

Answer (score 0):

JS toolkits sometime render different HTML from what you would expect, usually this is done for improved visual effects. It may be that ExJS puts an image over the checkbox in order to make it look nicer (I'm not familiar with it).

In any case UFT comes with a built in ExJS web extensibility which may solve your problem. You can install this by running the special Web2.0 installation under UFT's `installations` sub-folder.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this is using UFT image based identification feature